# Problema com nth-child

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

HTML:

```
<div class='linha visivel'>Visivel</div>
<div class='linha visivel'>Visivel</div>
<div class='linha oculto' style='display:none'>Invisivel</div>
<div class='linha visivel'>Visivel</div>
```

CSS:

```
.visivel:nth-child(odd) { background: yellow }
.visivel:nth-child(even) { background: green }
```

Resultado encontrado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- 1º linha com classe visivel AMARELA
- 2º linha com classe visivel VERDE
- 3º linha com classe visivel VERDE

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- 1º linha com classe visivel AMARELA
- 2º linha com classe visivel VERDE
- 3º linha com classe visivel AMARELA

http://jsfiddle.net/vk6xqnhb/

Pelo que eu entendo, o nth-child deveria pintar alternadamente as divs com a classe visivel. Mas como há uma div oculta no meio ele acaba não fazendo isso corretamente.

Estou enganado sobre o comportamento? Como corrigir?

Comment: A mesma dúvida que você tem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057925/select-odd-even-child-excluding-the-hidden-child (Solução marcada)

Comment: O comportamento é este mesmo, pois o seletor funciona com base nos nós do DOM e não se aplica somente ao que é selecionado pelo CSS. O que você poderia fazer neste caso é pintar as linhas usando JavaScript, por exemplo.

Comment: Eu conseguiria fazer com jQuery, mas estava justamente tentando evitar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado nos comentários e na resposta do SO em inglês não tive outra solução a não ser usar o jQuery:

```
 $(".visivel:even").css("background-color", "green");
 $(".visivel:odd").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comentário do @utluiz sobre o comportamento "inesperado":

> O comportamento é este mesmo, pois o seletor funciona com base nos nós
>   do DOM e não se aplica somente ao que é selecionado pelo CSS.

Comment: Poderia explicar, pelo menos, porque o comportamento ocorre? .__.

Comment: Porque o seletor `nth-child` seleciona as divs de acordo com o pai. Como o pai de todas as divs é o mesmo (`body`), a div invisível é contada por ter o mesmo pai das outras.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o funcionamento do `nth-child(odd)` e `nth-child(even)`: Quando se coloca `even` e `odd` vai colorir as linhas pares e ímpares, respectivamente.

Outro modo de fazer, sem usar jQuery, é você criar uma `div` e colocar todos os elementos dentro dela (de acordo com essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058442/5327226)):

```css
.todas {
  line-height: 1.2em;  
  background-color: yellow; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, green 50%);
  background-size: 100% 2.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="todas">
  <div class='linha visivel'>Visivel</div>
  <div class='linha visivel'>Visivel</div>
  <div class='linha oculto' style='display:none'>Invisivel</div>
  <div class='linha visivel'>Visivel</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas o nth-child está vinculado a classe "visível", ele não deveria computar essa div com display:none pois ela não tem a classe "visivel", isso que é estranho

Comment: @JoaoPaulo o `nth-child` e `nth-of-type` são tratados no elemento, e não na classe. `algo.classe:nth-of-type()` e `algo:nth-of-type().classe` são sinônimos (independente da omissão do `algo`). Os `nth` são computados primeiro em qualquer uma das duas formas, e só depois é considerada a classe. Se pretende mudar em JS a condição hidden ou não, uma gambiarra seria usar duas tags diferentes, em vez de mudar a classe dinamicamente (alternar entre span e div em vez de mudar o display: e definir o span como sendo o invisivel). Mas isso só é válido se a semântica da parte oculta não for relevante.